# Powershell to server finishes but waits a minute before finish

Tags: powershell, server, invoke-command

So I use this very simple script (in this case) and script is done in cca 10 seconds, but then it just waits for more than a minute and then finishes

Here is the printscreen of script run locally where script runs for more than a minute
[Script local](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0u4K.jpg)

And here is it on the server, run by same user, and same credentials where script runs around 2 seconds
[Script on server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ozda.jpg)

Does anyone have an idea why or what can I do?

```
$Username = 'xxxxxxx'
$Password = 'xxxxxxx'
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username,$pass

Write-Output 'Start:' 
Get-Date

Write-Output 'Server:'
Invoke-Command -ComputerName xxxxxxx.xxx.xxx.xxx-ScriptBlock { Get-Date } -credential $Cred

Write-Output 'Finish:' 
Get-Date
```

Thanks

David V.

Comment: Cannot reproduce.. Is your network slow? Is your computer also running other tasks?

Comment: No, my network is ok, working on vpn, yes there are other things running but neither is my cpu or ram used more than 80%, all other scripts that don't connect to another computers work fine